# Row value to columns

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007, pivot, ms-access-2010

I have the following table:

```
Name        Group
John        2A
John        1B
Barry       2A
Ron         1B
Ron         2A
Ron         2C
```

I am trying to create a query to separate the group column into a new column of for each instance.

Expected Result

```
Name        Group1      Group2      Group3
John        2A          1B
Barry       2A
Ron         1B          2A          2C
```

In this example I know that the max Groups are 3. So I made Group1, Group2, and Group3 columns.

Sort of like a crosstab, but I can't use a cross tab because the value options would need to be numeric and I have strings. At least not in MS-Access, which is what I am using.

Comment: why don't you expect the groups to be in the same columns?  `2A` in `Group2`, `1B` in `Group1` etc?

Comment: For Ron, what decides which value goes into group 1? It is not clear why '1B' goes there instead of '2A' or '2C'.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, MS Access does not have a `row_number()` function to easily assign a value to each item per `name`.  I would get the result the following way.

First, by using the query below you will return the `name`, `group` and an incremented number that is assigned for each group per person:

```
select name, 
  group, 
  (select count(*) 
   from yourtable t1 
   where yourtable.name = t1.name
     and yourtable.group<= t1.group) AS rw
from yourtable;
```

This query will give a result similar to :

```
+-------+-------+----+
|  name | group | rw |
+-------+-------+----+
| John  | 2A    |  1 |
| John  | 1B    |  2 |
| Barry | 2A    |  1 |
| Ron   | 1B    |  3 |
| Ron   | 2A    |  2 |
| Ron   | 2C    |  1 |
+-------+-------+----+
```

Then you can use the [`IIF()`](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/iif-function-HA001228853.aspx) function and the `max()` aggregate function to convert the values from rows into columns:

```
SELECT name,
  max(iif(rw=1, group, null)) as Group1,
  max(iif(rw=2, group, null)) as Group2,
  max(iif(rw=3, group, null)) as Group3
FROM 
(
  select name, 
    group, 
    (select count(*) 
        from yourtable t1 
        where yourtable.name = t1.name 
            and yourtable.group<= t1.group) AS rw
  from yourtable
) d
group by name
order by name;
```

This will give a result:

```
+-------+--------+--------+--------+
|  name | Group1 | Group2 | Group3 |
+-------+--------+--------+--------+
| Barry | 2A     |        |        |
| John  | 2A     | 1B     |        |
| Ron   | 2C     | 2A     | 1B     |
+-------+--------+--------+--------+
```

Edit:  Data in a table is not inherently ordered but if you have a column to place the data in the order you want using id, etc., then you should be able to alter the query to the following:

```
SELECT name, 
    max(iif(rw=1, group, null)) AS Group1, 
    max(iif(rw=2, group, null)) AS Group2,
    max(iif(rw=3, group, null)) AS Group3
FROM 
(
    SELECT name, 
      group, 
      (select count(*) 
       from table9 t1
       where yourtable.name = t1.name 
         and t1.id<= yourtable.id
        )  as rw
    from yourtable
) AS d
GROUP BY name
ORDER BY name;
```

The result will be:

```
+-------+--------+--------+--------+
|  name | Group1 | Group2 | Group3 |
+-------+--------+--------+--------+
| Barry | 2A     |        |        |
| John  | 2A     | 1B     |        |
| Ron   | 1B     | 2A     | 2C     |
+-------+--------+--------+--------+
```

Comment: I notice that the order changes in the first query.

Comment: @Rick I'm not sure I understand your comment.  What order do you want the data in?

Comment: I ran the first query and the rw coulnm gave the group number but not in the correct order. I even tried adding an autonumber field and including `order by id asc` in the subquery.

Comment: @Rick What order are you expecting the data in?

Comment: I want Group1 to be the first in the list from top to down, then Group2 second, and Group3 third. For example, with ron I am getting: Group1: 1B, Group2: 2C, Group3: 2A

Comment: @Rick Do you have a column that would keep the data in that order?  Data in a table is not inherently ordered

Comment: Like I said, I added the id field as autonumber to the table. Should keep it in the order originally intended.